# match any url with 2 digits after /page= and before /

Tags: regex

I am completely new to `regex` but I have a huge number of urls that follow the same basic form that I need to redirect to a specific url. I am trying to match 'fixed string' then 'any number between `1` and `999`' then `/`

Example

`../section/subsection/page=xx/ to redirect to ../new_section/new_subsection/`

where

it always starts `../section/subsection/page=`

`xx` is a number between `1` and `999`

and ends with a `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need only positive numbers and not 0, then use `[1-9]\d{0,2}`:

```
\.\.\/section\/subsection\/page=[1-9]\d{0,2}\/
```

https://regex101.com/r/aM1dN1/1

Comment: Perfect - this is EXACTLY what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Regex `\d{1,3}` will give you matching with all numbers from 0 to 999 and `[1-9]\d{0,2}` will give you matching with all numbers from 1 to 999

Well, for your url: `.*/page=[1-9]\d{0,2}/` or `.*/page=[1-9]{1,3}/`

Comment: Thank you. I needed a specific string prior and after the number but the method you provided for matching any number between 1-999 was great

Answer (score 0):

This will match anything that contains a `page=###` type string in the `url` and the capturing group will give you the page number.

`.*page=([1-9]{1,3})`

https://regex101.com/r/xZ0eO8/2

Comment: you regex will match 0 also

Comment: really? I thought it matches the first digit as 1-9 and then optionally 2 other digits.

Comment: @DanWood my regex will match any URL that contains `page=` and then the capturing group will take any following number that is between 1 and 3 digits long